# ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found(ng build --prod)

Tags: angular

I'm working on angular-cli. I got following errors.

> ERROR in ./src/main.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\material\matapp\src'
>    @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
>    @ multi ./src/main.ts

My `main.ts` file:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'; 
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'; 
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module'; 
import { environment } from './environments/environment'; 

if (environment.production) { 
    enableProdMode(); 
} 
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Kindly help me to resolve the issue.PFA[image]

Comment: My main.ts file is  import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

Comment: Which `angular-cli` version, you are using?

Comment: @angular/cli: 1.2.0

Comment: Not sure, but check your `package.json` where check version for `"enhanced-resolve": "^3.4.1",`

Comment: @avnesh shakya. not available

Comment: try this `ng build --prod --verbose` to find the inner errors in the project

Answer (score 7):

The real problem here is that the Angular CLI error messages are rubbish. This is how I solved it:

```
npm install enhanced-resolve@3.3.0
```

I found the solution a long, long way down this page: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7113

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I resolved by upgrading the angular cli to version 1.2.6.

Comment: can you please tell me how to upgrade angular cli version 1.2.0  to 1.2.6

Answer (score 1):

Change **"@angular/cli": "1.0.0",** from package.json to **"@angular/cli": "1.2.4"**

Make sure after changing from 1.0.0 ver to 1.2.4 to do **npm install** before you ng build ...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ng build -prod --aot=false
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a solution. Turning off AOT will get the build to go through, but loses all the benefits of it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and fixed it by deleting node_module and run npm install.